# How do I close a popover from inside of a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using AngularJS and AngularStrap, and I've been trying to create a popover that calls a function when a button is pushed and then if the function succeeds doing what it needs to do it automatically closes the popover. The popover inherits the parent scope, and the function I'm calling is on the parent scope, but the $hide function is not. I tried passing it via a parameter `ng-click="vm.newAsUnitPriceRule(stagingItem, $hide)`, but that did not work, apparently you can't pass the $hide function, it just results in undefined when you step in to the function.

```
<div class="popover">
    <a ng-click="$hide()"><small class="pull-right">X</small></a>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <button class="btn small newAsUnitPriceRule" ng-click="vm.newAsUnitPriceRule(stagingItem)">Pack As Unit Price</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn small newPackAsSizeRule" ng-click="vm.newPackAsSizeRule(stagingItem)">Pack As Size Rule</button>
        <br>
        <button class="btn small newRule" ng-click="vm.newRule(stagingItem)">Custom Rule</button>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine passing `$hide` as an argument [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NMLw4FGzxKInImgy0aGt?p=preview). Any thoughts on what the differences are between this Plunker and your code? Can you fork it and modify it so that it exhibits the same behavior as what you're seeing?

Comment: Strange, when I pulled the code down on my work system it worked, but it wasn't working last night at home. I blame gremlins